# Does this song use chromatic mediant in G major? and what other music theory concepts this song's verse utilize

Tags: chords, chord-theory, composition, chord-progressions, chromatic

I'm currently learning basic music theory and along the way I review old songs on my playlist then analyze what key, chord progression and somehow discover the composer's way of creating music.

The specific song "*214 by Rivermaya*" is clearly written on **G major** with chord progression of **I, vi, ii**... in its intro.

What confuses me is the use of **E** and **A** major chords in the verse. I just recently explored the concept of **"chromatic mediant"**. Based on its concept, **E** is the parallel key of **G major**'s sub-median note (**E minor**). But the **A major** chord doesn't look like a chromatic mediant since it belongs to supertonic of both **G major** and **G minor** scale. What could be the explanation that describes the structure of the verse? Should I also look in the concept of modes or other music theory concepts to easily understand how songs are composed? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me tha verse has actually gone into key E. There are A and Am, both of which are commonplace in key E, and using Bm instead of E7 is a not unusual way to get to IV, A. The Bm has B, D, F♯, so sounds somewhat like E9.

On the 2nd question - modes will and do appear in some songs, although nowhere near as common as the 'main' modes of Ionian and Aeolian, but being aware of where 'home' is - the tonic - will be the best clue as to whether a song's in a different mode.